# Allowing iframe overflow on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, iframe

I have to display a 3rd party link (cross-domain) on a webpage that is displayed on tablets and phones.

The 3rd party has decided to display a modal window, vertically centered on initial page load.

The problem I am running into is that the phones (iOS 5 mobile Safari, in particular) automatically resize `iframe` to fit the content, causing the modal window to be rendered off the bottom of the screen, due to it being many, many pixels tall.

I have tried everything I can think of to get the iframe to just display in a fixed size, but nothing works.

1. Adding `height` attribute or styles is ignored, even with `!important`
2. Wrapping the iframe in a `div` with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` seems to work, but in this situation, still results in the iframe expanding and, thus, displaying the modal window off-screen.
3. Adding `scrolling="no"` allows the iframe to be displayed in a fixed size, but I can't get the iframe to scroll now.

I'm wondering if there are any alternatives to `iframe` or if there is anything I can do to get an iframe to properly display with a fixed size.

Oh, and I must mention, I cannot simply open the 3rd party link in a new window/tab, since this webpage is baked into an app, which I have no control over.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            iframe
            {
                height: 100px !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe style="height:100px;" height="100" src="http://dump.mrslayer.com/test2.html"></iframe>

        <script>
            setTimeout( function( ) {
                var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' )[0];
                iframe.style.height = "100px";
                iframe.height = 100;
            }, 1000 );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe the css that goes along might help.

Comment: @GCyrillus, I have included the entire HTML code of a most basic example, with various attempts, none of which do anything on iOS 5 Safari.

Comment: okay, i see no absolute nor fixed position & iframe standing alone. The trick could be to set margin or borders to body/html to squeeze body area instead sizing iframe that grows 100% anyway ?.

Comment: The frame still resizes and, thus, causes the body to expand, regardless of heights, margins, or paddings on the `body` and `html`, or a wrapper `div`.

Comment: arghh, sorry not to be more helpfull.

Comment: iframe {transform:scale(0.8) ;transform-origin:center;} ? last simple idea i have

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP, but this prints the entire document contents inline with your document.

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://dump.mrslayer.com/test2.html");
?>
```

If it's an issue, you can use regex or something like that to remove everything before the `<body>` tag and after the `</body>` tag after you have the `file_get_contents()`.

You can include this function in a `<div>`, which should be easier to control with CSS.  This is the easiest alternative to an iframe I can think of.